# Populate a dropdown menu with values from a Database

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a database with different products in it. Each product is available in different colours. What I want to achieve is in a dropdown menu select the colours in which the product is available and then load the page with the product of chosen colour.

I have got the following:
The product is initially chosen as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['product_id'])) {
 $query_RS_Product = ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = :pid AND hidden ='no'");
 $RS_Product = $conn->prepare($query_RS_Product) or die(errorinfo());
$RS_Product->bindValue(':pid', $_GET['product_id']);
$RS_Product->execute();
$row_RS_Product =$RS_Product->fetch();
```

Now I want to select the colours that are available for this product and create a dropdown menu

```
<form><select name="productColor" id="pColor" class="dropmenu" >

<?php  
    $productcolor = $row_RS_Product['Model'];
    $productcolor="SELECT * FROM products WHERE (Model = ':productcolor'  AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Color";
    $resultp=$conn->prepare($productcolor);
    $resultp->bindValue(':productcolor', $productcolor );
    $resultp->execute();

    while ($pcolor = $resultp->fetch($productcolor)) {
        echo '<option value="Select Color">' . htmlspecialchars($pcolor['Color']) . '</option>';
    }
   ?>
</select>
</form>
```

However the menu will not populate
Any help welcome

Comment: any errors? is `$resultp` not empty?

Comment: what has this got to do with jquery?

Comment: i hope you have product_id in your url

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error.

Comment: @Fred Could you please point me in the right direction as the rest of the page is loading fine

Comment: Two obvious errors are in here `WHERE (Model = ':productcolor'` - 1) The bracket `(` which should be removed; that's a parse error right there. 2) The quotes around the placeholder; those need to be removed. The `product_id` GET array is unknown as to how you're using that, as is how you're using the `name="productColor"` attribute. All I can say here, is for you to check for errors via error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - I can't submit an answer for this, because of the unknowns. Check the 2 points.

Comment: Another one I spotted `$resultp->bindValue(':productcolor', $productcolor );` - You can't bind a "query", you need to bind a value/array. You need to rename your variable in `$productcolor="SELECT`. You also tagged as jquery, but no code to support the question.

Comment: @Fred thanks for that it is working now. I corrected my obvious mistakes (how stupid of me)

Comment: You're welcome. What would you like to do with the question? Have my comments themselves solved it?

Comment: @Ria I posted an answer below should you want to mark the question as solved.

Comment: I still need to solve when the colour is selected it goes to the corresponding product page with that colour, however in order to do that I'll need to Select a couple more fields from the DB. I'll get there in the end. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Ria Well, to give you a few pointers here in regards to your comment just above; you need to get the value from the name attribute in the `<select>` being `$_GET['productColor']` and assigning a variable to it. Then, redirect with a header while passing an argument to it for the corresponding page you wish to use. I.e.: `header("Location: file.php?$var_assigned_from_GET_array_in_select"); exit;`. I hope this serves you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transcribed from (my) comments.

Two obvious errors are in here `WHERE (Model = ':productcolor'`

**1)** The bracket `(` which should be removed; that's a parse error right there.

**2)** The quotes around the placeholder; those need to be removed.

Then `$resultp->bindValue(':productcolor', $productcolor );` You can't bind a "query", you need to bind a value/array.

You need to rename your variable in `$productcolor="SELECT ...` to something else, and using the variable for the (GET) array.

Both PHP's error reporting and PDO error handling would have been of help here.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php